# How do I execute a .SQL file from Excel VBA code?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

*** Update to below ***
I decided to give up on executing the file and decided to pass a long query string via ADO.Execute  with UseTransaction set to True and no recordset returned. I am running into a new problem where only some of the records are inserted although the error code is 0.  Total execution time is under a second. Command timeout is 30, Connection timeout is 15.

Within the query, I am running 6 deletes and then usually over 54 inserts. About 32 inserted rows actually appear in the DB, and the remainder of the query is ignored, again with no error returned.  Maybe there is a timeout on the SQL server side, a max string length, or max number of commands it can accept from ADO?  If I paste the entire query directly into the SQL Server Management Studio, the whole thing executes no matter how long it is.  There seems to be a limitation on the SQL Server side.  Ideas?
*** End Update ***

I am using my Excel data to generate a complex query, sending it to a file. The query locks the DB, deletes records, generates a new key using @ variables and uses the @ variables in INSERT statements. Finally, it runs a COMMIT statement.  There are at least 100 statements in the .sql file.

After generating the .sql file, I would like to execute the file from the code and receive the success status. I would like to do this in one shot, instead of hitting the DB 100 or more separate times and checking the status of every statement.

I have tried searching the web for an answer, but no luck tracking it down.

How can I do that?

If I can't trigger the file, I guess I will have to run each statement individually (lock DB, run individual deletes, run individual inserts), checking success after each. If all is well I COMMIT or if not, do ROLLBACK. Will that work?

Thank you.

If it helps, here is a sample of my SQL file to get an idea what kinds of statements are included.

```
use MY_DB_NAME; 
declare @i_xseq int;
declare @deleteBeforeInsert int;
set @deleteBeforeInsert = 1;

begin transaction MyTransaction;


-- ***********************************   DELETE FUTURE EVENTS
-- Delete all future records using application ID 12 and having a start date after the start date:

if (@deleteBeforeInsert = 1)
BEGIN

  delete from dbo.TableA
where EVENT_XSEQ in (select X_SEQ from dbo.TAbleB where START > CAST('2014-03-26 14:22:01' as datetime) and APPLICATION_ID = 12);
END

-- ************************************ GET NEXT SEQUENCE #
-- begin retrieve new @i_xseq
select @i_xseq=LAST_ID from [dbo].[AKey] WITH (XLOCK,READPAST) where TABLE_NAME = 'TableB';
Update [dbo].[AKey]
Set LAST_ID = LAST_ID + 1
where TABLE_NAME = 'TableB';

select @i_xseq=LAST_ID from [dbo].[AKey] where TABLE_NAME = 'TableB';
-- end retrieve new @i_xseq

-- RUN Inserts (many)
insert into dbo.TableB
  (VAL1, VAL2,X_SEQ)
Values
  (1110, 37673.70, @i_xseq);

-- *************************************  END AND COMMIT
insert into dbo.SCHEDULE_LOG
(DESCRIPTION, X_UPDATED, X_BY)
Values
('Close_Scheduling', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'MY_ID');

COMMIT transaction MyTransaction;
```

Answer (score 0):

In a separate module create a Function or Procedure that writes all the lines in your SQL statement into a string. Than pass that string into an open database connection. 
You will need to include "Mircosoft ActiveX Data Objects Library" in your project.

```
Public Function rstSomeName()

Dim sSql As String

sSql = ""
sSql = sSql & "use MY_DB_NAME;                               " & vbCrLf
sSql = sSql & "declare @i_xseq int;                          " & vbCrLf
sSql = sSql & " etc.. to the end of you sql statement        " & vbCrLf


Set rstSomeName= New ADODB.Recordset
rstSomeName.Open sSql, "Your Database Connection String"

End Function
```

Comment: The string will handle over 100,000 characters? Do you know what kind of error return I will get from running a big query like this?  Do you think I should leave off the commit/rollback statement, check the error status, and then either send commit or rollback or does that final statement have to be part of the first transaction?

Comment: The limit on a VBA String is around 2GB, which is around 2 billion Characters.  I would be more concerned with if you'll be able to pass that much through your data connection, what ever that may be.  And in that case. Why not create this as a Stored procedure and just call it from the vba code?  Any errors would be Oracle returned errors which you could handle with on error. And finally you shouldn't have to modify any of your SQL code if it runs now on your database than passing it to the database shouldn't be an issue either.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried some of your ideas and updated my question above. Can you take another look?  I need to get permission from client before trying stored procedures.

Comment: Just an idea, but instead of making it one long string. Why not load pieces of it? You can do it in stages. Load string1...submit...load string2 submit... etc. This way you could probably find the error easier.

Comment: Hi Keith - There is no error produced. If I paste the whole long query into the SQL Server Manager, it runs fine.  I ultimately would like this as one long transaction so that I can roll back the entire thing if there are any problems. If I put in a few inserts and then a few more in a separate transaction, I believe I couldn't roll them back correctly.

Comment: After you load the string have you tried manually taking the fully loaded string and pasting it in to the sql server?  Do you get the result you expect?  Could be the string is not loading as you expect it.  Also breaking it into chunks until you identify the bug.  Then putting it back into the one string was what I was getting at, simply for testing

Comment: When I paste the entire string into the SQL Server GUI, it runs perfectly and all rows are inserted. There are no errors produced in this way, nor when it is run via VBA/ADODB. There is only missing data.

Comment: Im not sure at this point.   The only thing I can think of might be the connection method.  Maybe try different drivers?